# Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Tags: root, dpkg, lock

```
(base) rusiru@rusiru-X556UV:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading packages lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package packettracer needs to be installed, but I can't find an archive for it.
(base) rusiru@rusiru-X556UV:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
(base) rusiru@rusiru-X556UV:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading packages lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package packettracer needs to be installed, but I can't find an archive for it.
(base) rusiru@rusiru-X556UV:~$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall packettracer
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
(base) rusiru@rusiru-X556UV:~$ sudo dpkg -l packettracer
Desired-Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/half-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
pHR packettracer   7.3.0        amd64        (no description available)
(base) rusiru@rusiru-X556UV:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading packages lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package packettracer needs to be installed, but I can't find an archive for it.
(base) rusiru@rusiru-X556UV:~$
```

I tried this but didn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use root, not sudo. I've seen all  kinds of apt failures when sudo is used instead of proper root.

Comment: Simply retrying the command may fix the issue, the locks are there to prevent two things trying to update at the same time. If that fails to resolve the issue then check that the directory /var/lib/dpkg exists (if it doesn't then stop immediately) and see what `fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` says. Hopefully it will give you one or more numbers (process ids). Use `ps -lp 1234` (change 1234 to the numbers from fuser) and see if you want to kill these processes. and then try again.

Answer (score 6):

Your `apt-get install --reinstall` command doesn't have a sudo in front of it.

A command such as `sudo x && y` *only* runs the `x` command under `sudo`; the `y` command runs with normal user privileges.

So if you want to use that syntax you should do `sudo x && sudo y`.

Answer (score 3):

It worked with the below one on Kali Linux

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Comment: Hello! Could you clarify what worked? Was you able to skip reinstalling a package when apt complained that you need to reinstall it?

Comment: @Roman Riabenko - I was trying to upgrade libraries, packages in Kali and hit with the "Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?".

Comment: So, your problem was that you skipped the second `sudo` the same way as described in the question and you fixed it by adding that second `sudo` after `&&` as described in [the most upvoted answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557417/423679). Right?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty late but typing
`sudo su`
And retrying the command you were going to do is more simple.

Comment: Notice that [Stephen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557417/117549) points out the lack of `sudo` before the `apt-get install --reinstall ...` portion, which avoids an unnecessary full `su` to root.